# Triple integral over a half hemisphere?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

> Calculate the integral $\displaystyle \iiint_K (x + 2) d{x} d{y} d{z}$ when $K$ is
> given by the inequalities $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1$ and $z ≥ 0$.
> [image]

But the correct answer is $\frac{4\pi}3$ and they gave a clue which is to use symmetric properties but I don't know how.

Comment: You have a serious typo. In your formula for $x$ you have $\cos\phi$ where it should be $\sin\phi$. You also forgot the $r$ in the formula for $y$, but that didn’t show up.

Comment: oh shit, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

- Small mistake: since $z\ge0,$ $\phi\in[0,\pi/2],$ not $[0,\pi].$
- Big mistake:
  $$\iiint \sin\phi\cdot(\dots)dr d\theta d\phi\ne\int_0^\pi\sin\phi d\phi\iint\left(\int_0^1\dots dr\right)d\theta d\phi.$$
- Easy solution: $\displaystyle \iiint_Kxdxdydz=0$
  by symmetry, and $\displaystyle \iiint 2dxdydz=$
  twice the volume of half the unit sphere$=\dfrac{4π}3.$

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate more on the last point?

Comment: $\iiint_{K\cap\{x>0\}} x~\mathrm dx~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d z=\iiint_{K\cap\{x< 0\}} -x~\mathrm dx~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d z$ because $K$ is reflectively symmetric across the $y{-}z$ plane, and $\iiint_K 1~\mathrm dx~\mathrm dy~\mathrm d z$ is the volume of $K$, which is a hemisphere of radius $1$. @Need_MathHelp

Comment: @GrahamKemp isn't the function x+2?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Integration is linear.  $${\iiint_K (x+2)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d z} = {\iiint_K x~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d z} + {2~\iiint_K 1~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d z}$$